# Any issue with having two public functions, in different models, but with the same name?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationships

I'm writing a web app using the Laravel framework. I have two models where I have created a public function, using the same name, to form an Eloquent Relationship. I want to know if this is bad practice, or if it will cause me any problems.

Here is my code for my WorkOrder model:

```
/**
 * Get the aircraft that owns the work order.
 */
public function aircraft()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Aircraft::class);
}
```

Here is my code for my Customer model:

```
/**
 * Get all of the aircraft for the customer.
 */
public function aircraft()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Aircraft::class);
}
```

Comment: No, that won't cause any problems. However, it would seem that the customer model should be aircraft**s**, pluralized.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by `aircraft**s**`

Comment: technical problems no - management maybe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine as is and will work with no issues, as @Ohgodwhy commented you'd want to pluralize the function name for `hasMany` or `belongsToMany` relationships. in this case however it's a moot point as aircraft is the plural of aircraft.